# How to build a WebView2 application with MinGW toolset?

Tags: winapi, webview, mingw

It isn't much information on this topic on the Internet. Guess most people use Visual Studio to build [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/) applications. So far, I've found these 2 projects [jchv/webview2-in-mingw](https://github.com/jchv/webview2-in-mingw) and [webview/webview](https://github.com/webview/webview#webview-for-cc-developers). The second one I cannot even build. The first one seems more promising. It can be built with MinGW toolset and also Visual Studio. However, when running the built demo, function `CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions` always returns error code `0x80070002`, no matter which toolset was used to build the demo. The error code `0x80070002` means "The system cannot find the file specified." What file am I missing? Help~ Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: webview2-in-mingw is just a proof of concept, so I wouldn't use that (yet). the webview project aims to be cross-platform and it builds fine with MinGW-w64 using CMake. However when run its test application it quickly opens and closes a window, so it doesn't seem fully functional. The real WebView2 API is described here though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32

Comment: @BrechtSanders Looks like you have the same result when running webview2-in-mingw. It says "Call to CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions failed!" and then close itself. That message came from webview2-in-mingw/Src/main.cpp:158. It is because `CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions` failed and returned the error code `0x80070002` which is mentioned in the question. I'll try to contact the author today and ask him why he put this demo online when its very first webview2 call failed. It probably works in some circumstance.